# Asset uploads failing on new installation of Craft CMS

Tags: assets, php, upload, installation, configuration

New (local) installation of Craft on Mac OSX Yosemite, working well except uploading an asset doesn't complete. The progress bar hangs and the spinner never stops spinning.

Craft index.php is located in `/Users/Penguin2/Sites/craft.dev/`
Craft application files are in `/Users/Penguin2/Sites/craft/`
PHP open_basedir is `/Users/Penguin2/Sites/`

The PHP log indicates the following:

```
[21-Jan-2015 18:04:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/tmp/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/Users/Penguin2/Sites) in Unknown on line 0
```

I assume I need to change the location where Craft stores temp files to a directory under the PHP open_basedir but I can't find the setting anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to set [upload_tmp_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) in your php.ini file to be a path under your openbase_dir paths.

Or just remove the openbase_dir restrictions.

Comment: FYI to others - I also had to go into the Settings > Assets > Sources and fix the asset file system path. I am working with the "On the rocks" demo site which had a default asset path of something like ../public/images/drinks when it should have been simply images/drinks.